# Domain name and selfhosting in Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, hosting, self-hosting, actix-web

I wrote a website in sveltekit Did SSG and using Actix web I wrote http server to serve the html files in Azure I binded the server to X.X.X.X:10000 and enable inbound port in network setting of the virtual machine with source as * and destination as 10000 now my website is visiable at public ip Y.Y.Y.Y:10000 Now I brought a domain name from hostinger and Added a DNS record type-A Content-Y.Y.Y.Y name-www .Now my website is visable at [www.domainname.com:10000/](http://www.domainname.com:10000/) but I want my website to be visiable at [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com)

I searched for solution some say to use reverse proxy, but still i think i can do just by adjusting the network settings in azure .Help me with this and also give a brief explanation

Answer (score 0):

Network security groups do not deal with port mapping. They apply security rules. "Source as * and destination as 10000" means "From any port that wants to reach port 10000".

You can redirect HTTP port(s) to 10000 from a VM in front of your current VM. But you can also redirect directly from your VM using a Web server, but you'll need to open the HTTP(s) ports on your VM. Alternatively, you can redirect using Azure Network services such as [Azure Load Balancer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/manage-port-forwarding-for-backend-pool-with-azure-load-balancer/) or Application Gateway.